# how to get the last selected row in a UITableView before a segue is executed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, segue, selecteditem

i have inserted a new row in a UITableView and now i tap another cell (also highlighted through a breakpoint in the debugger, after that, only the tapped row is selected):

[image]

the new row (UITextField) has the text "new" and the selected cell has the title "Hobby"

On the tap of the now selected row/cell "Hobby" i must fire a segue to another TableViewController (ColumnViewController)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if self.currentEdit != nil {
        self.currentEdit.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    if segue.identifier == "SetupColumn" {
        let cell = sender as! EditCell
        let destControlller = segue.destinationViewController as! ColumnViewController
        destControlller.kategorieID = cell.nameField.tag
    }
}
```

but i must know, that the row/cell "Hobby" is tapped cause i have to popup an alert before calling the segue. I only must know, that the row is different to the added one, not *which* row is tapped.

self.currentEdit contains the actually selected TextField, but there i just have the added row. :-(

**update**

I got the answer of **beyowulf**, that can you see below. I thought, the problem is solved, but when playing with it some time, i suddenly (!?) get the error

> app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'SetupColumn''

The answer of beyowulf was:

```
 Don't connect your segue to the your table view cells. Connect it to your view controller then call it explicitly when you want to segue
```

My question is now: how may i connect my segue to my **view controller** instead **connecting it to the table view cell**?

Comment: Don't connect your segue to the your table view cells. Connect it to your view controller then call it explicitly when you want to segue. For example, you can call `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SetupColumn", sender:tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if you need to segue after that particular selection.

Comment: ctrl & drag from your view controller (try doing it from the header of the scene or even the view controller listed from the sidebar) to the other view controller

Comment: @Meriw yes, i tried this too as subscibed here https://www.codebeaulieu.com/29/prepareForSegue, but i also get the shown error

Comment: Are you sure you have set the segue's identifier to "SetupColumn"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` give you what you need?

To add a segue from your view controller, right-click on it and choose "Triggered Segues", drag from the 'manual' row to the segue's destination.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Graham Perks! let row = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow in prepareForSegue has the result nil. Is that the right  place?

Comment: still the same... @Graham Perks :-(

Answer (score 0):

to help others, who are just as stupid as me ;-)

the solution is found in the anwers of **beyowulf** and **Meriw**

i had to add  **Manual Segue** from my SetUpViewController (source) and ColumnViewController (target) as shown in the screenshot
[image]

and name it **SetupColumn**

[image]

and then i only had to add

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SetupColumn", sender:tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
}
```